Изменение пропусков в тексте с помощью EditText
Есть вот такой текст ___ Антон говорит по-русски ___, ___ Юйхан - это TextView элемент RecyclerView. По нажатии на этот элемент, должна открываться клавиатура, и нужно, чтобы изменялись только пропуски, а остальной текст оставался неизменным.
Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791180/multiline-edittext-where-parts-are-not-editable-like-fill-in-the-blanks

Спасибо большое
